# How do I capture PHP output into a variable?

Tags: php, xml

I'm generating a ton of XML that is to be passed to an API as a post variable when a user click on a form button. I also want to be able to show the user the XML before hand.

The code is sorta like the following in structure:

```
<?php
    $lots of = "php";
?>

<xml>
    <morexml>

<?php
    while(){
?>
    <somegeneratedxml>
<?php } ?>

<lastofthexml>

<?php ?>

<html>
    <pre>
      The XML for the user to preview
    </pre>

    <form>
        <input id="xml" value="theXMLagain" />
    </form>
</html>
```

My XML is being generated with a few while loops and stuff. It then needs to be shown in the two places (the preview and the form value).

My question is. How do I capture the generated XML in a variable or whatever so I only have to generate it once and then just print it out as apposed to generating it inside the preview and then again inside the form value?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<xml/>
<?php $xml = ob_get_clean(); ?>
<input value="<?php echo $xml ?>" />͏͏͏͏͏͏
```

Comment: @Jleagle $xml = ob_get_clean() will return output buffert and clean output. It essentially executes both ob_get_contents() and ob_end_clean()

Comment: Don't forget to use `htmlentities($xml)`, or else your site will break if the xml has `"` in it.

Answer (score 52):

Put this at your start:

```
ob_start();
```

And to get the buffer back:

```
$value = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php and the individual functions for more information.

Answer (score 11):

It sounds like you want [PHP Output Buffering](https://www.php.net/ob_start)

```
ob_start(); 
// make your XML file

$out1 = ob_get_contents();
//$out1 now contains your XML
```

Note that output buffering stops the output from being sent, until you "flush" it. See the [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.examples.php) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

When using frequently, a little helper could be *helpful*:

```php
class Helper
{
    /**
     * Capture output of a function with arguments and return it as a string.
     */
    public static function captureOutput(callable $callback, ...$args): string
    {
        ob_start();
        $callback(...$args);
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        return $output;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
<?php
$string = <<<XMLDoc
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<doc>
  <title>XML Document</title>
  <lotsofxml/>
  <fruits>
XMLDoc;

$fruits = array('apple', 'banana', 'orange');

foreach($fruits as $fruit) {
  $string .= "\n    <fruit>".$fruit."</fruit>";
}

$string .= "\n  </fruits>
</doc>";
?>
<html>
<!-- Show XML as HTML with entities; saves having to view source -->
<pre><?=str_replace("<", "&lt;", str_replace(">", "&gt;", $string))?></pre>
<textarea rows="8" cols="50"><?=$string?></textarea>
</html>
```