# Include whole content of a file and echo it

Tags: php, echo

I need to echo entire content of included file. I have tried the below:

```
echo "<?php include ('http://www.example.com/script.php'); ?>";

echo "include (\"http://www.example.com/script.php\");";
```

But neither works? Does PHP support this?

Comment: Have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171318/how-do-i-capture-php-output-into-a-variable

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?
Do you want to echo the result of the include() ?
Do you want to echo the content of the file you are trying to include ?

Comment: Try to echo the content of the include file

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just do:

```
include("http://www.mysite.com/script.php");
```

Or:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.mysite.com/script.php");
```

Notes:

- This may slow down your page due to network latency or if the other server is slow.
- This requires `allow_url_fopen` to be on for your PHP installation. Some hosts turn it off.
- This will not give you the PHP code, it'll give you the HTML/text output.

Comment: just to tell you, I don't know why, that in my case just the `include` version works

Answer (score 4):

Shortest way is:

```
readfile('http://www.mysite.com/script.php');
```

That will directly output the file.

Answer (score 3):

Echo prints something to the output buffer - it's not parsed by PHP. If you want to include something, just do it

```
include ('http://www.mysite.com/script.php');
```

You don't need to print out PHP source code, when you're writing PHP source code.

Comment: hi, I tried this and get a error saying direct file access is not allowed

Comment: Sounds like allow_url_fopen is turned off. If your host permits it, you can try putting "php_value allow_url_fopen 1" in a .htaccess file.

Comment: His question was how to do a particluar task, not whether or not eh should. Telling him what he does and does not need to do does not help answer the question. Unless asked, his strategy is up to him.

Comment: This is better as you want the file to still be parsed

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you're asking, but you can't really include something via http and expect to see code, since the server will parse the file.

If "script.php" is a local file, you could try something like:

```
$file = file_get_contents('script.php');
echo $file;
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the exact answer to your question, but why don't you just close the echo statement, insert your include statement, and then add a new echo statement?

```
<?php
  echo 'The brown cow';
  include './script.php';
  echo 'jumped over the fence.';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Matt is correct with `readfile()` but it also may be helpful for someone to look into the PHP file handling functions
[manual entry for fpassthru](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php)

```
<?php

$f = fopen($filepath, 'r');

fpassthru($f);

fclose($f);

?>
```