# How can I echo the whole content of a .html file in PHP?

Tags: php, html, echo

Is there a way I can echo the whole content of a .html file in PHP?

For example, I have some sample.html file, and I want to echo that filename, so its content should be displayed.

Comment: `Include` should do .) or `readfile()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include whole content of a file and echo it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921479/include-whole-content-of-a-file-and-echo-it)

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You should use [`readfile()`](http://php.net/readfile):

```
readfile("/path/to/file");
```

This will read the file and send it to the browser in one command. This is essentially the same as:

```
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/file");
```

except that [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) may cause the script to crash for large files, while `readfile()` won't.

Comment: Is there any way I can first check if that file exists in the folder, and only if it does, to execute the above command?

Comment: [`file_exists()`](http://php.net/file_exists) can check whether a file or directory by that name exists, and [`is_file()`](http://php.net/is_file) can be used to check that a file exists *and is a regular file*. In you case, `is_file()` should probably be used.

Comment: Strange, but when I change the file_get_contents into readfile, it adds 1191 at the bottom, and I have no idea where that number comes from :) Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use `echo readfile()`? Because `readfile()` returns the length of the file (which seems to be 1191 bytes), if you add `echo` before `readfile()`, it will print the length *after* you print the file. Simply remove `echo` and it should work. :)

Comment: Hahaha what a simple and correct explanation, funny thing thoug :) Thank you so much (and thanks goes to the other guys as well), you helped me a lot, thanks again.

Answer (score 20):

Just use:

```
<?php
    include("/path/to/file.html");
?>
```

That will echo it as well. This also has the benefit of executing any PHP in the file.

If you need to do anything with the contents, use file_get_contents(),

For example,

```
<?php
    $pagecontents = file_get_contents("/path/to/file.html");

    echo str_replace("Banana", "Pineapple", $pagecontents);

?>
```

This doesn't execute code in that file, so be careful if you expect that to work.

I usually use:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/path/to/file/as/in/url.html");
```

as then I can move files without breaking the includes.

Comment: Thhanks for the quick response :) Can you write me an example, please? I edited my question. Thanks. P.S. You have no code after: "Just use:" ?

Comment: Ah, forgot to indent it properly!

Comment: `readfile` works, but `include` doesn't seem to work for images.....`header('Content-Type: image/png'); include('test.png');exit;` shows a "broken" image.

Comment: Note that you should not use `include` for echoing the content of arbitrary files. If an attacker manages to upload a PHP file and you call `include` on it, you've got yourself a remote code execution exploit. Use `readfile()` instead.

Answer (score 14):

If you want to make sure the HTML file doesn't contain any PHP code and will not be executed as PHP, ***do not*** use `include` or `require`. Simply do:

```
echo file_get_contents("/path/to/file.html");
```