# Include HTML file with a table into PHP

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a table stored in an HTML file and I want to insert that into a WordPress page. I used `echo file_get_contents('table.html')` but it didn't display anything. Then I tried `echo htmlentities (file_get_contents('table.html'))`. This just outputs the HTML code into the page but does not render it. How do I make the table display correctly ?

HTML table is something like:

```
<table class="fao-pricing-table-additional">
 <tr>
    <th class="fao-table-plan-details-header" rowspan="2">Plan Details</th>
    <th class="fao-table-plan-starter-header">STARTER</th>
    <th class="fao-table-plan-business-header">BUSINESS</th>
    <th class="fao-table-plan-enterprise-header">ENTERPRISE</th>
    <th class="fao-table-plan-corporate-header">CORPORATE</th>
</tr>
<tr>.......
```

Comment: If i understand your question correctly [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-html-snippet/) will help. This plugin will add HTML, CSS and javascript code to your pages and posts easily using shortcodes.

Comment: Thank you replying. I just tried that but It didn't output anything.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539849/how-to-echo-the-whole-content-of-an-html-file-in-php

Comment: @IndikaRatnayake check out my updated answer and see if that works

Comment: @katwekibs I tried readfile() but it output a number and does not render the HTML table.

Comment: Is it not outputting anything or can you just not see it in oyour html page?  Check in the html source whether the html has been output or not?  It is very unlikely that it works when calling html_entities but not otherwise!

Comment: @wolfsgang Thank you very much. That's exactly what I was looking for. However I want to learn how to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an `include()` statement to render HTML/PHP on a webpage

**Example**

```
<div>
  <p>The table will be between this paragraph</p>

    <?php 
        include("table.html");
    ?>

  <p>And this paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '**./**' to indicate the relative path to the file.

**Example**:
   echo file_get_contents("./table.html");