# How to printf an include html

Tags: php

I included an html file like this, so that it is not displayed when the site loads:

```
<div id="menugrp0" class="menuhide">
<?php include 'menugrp0.html';  ?>
</div>
```

Now I want it to be shown at a specific spot. I am using this php code, to get some variables which are transported with the `$_SESSION`. I am using this kind of question for some simple html links, in which case it works perfectly:

```
if ($_SESSION['gruppe'] == $h['gruppe']) {     
  printf(' menugrp0.html');
}
```

I know that this is not working at all at the moment for this included html. I also tried to add the `<?php [...] ?>` tag inside the printf, which is also not working.

Is it possible to show a hidden included html file with a printf tag?

Comment: Just include it in the spot where you want the content shown instead? Seems a lot simpler.

Comment: But there are like 4 different include files. Only the one should be shown, which matches with the `$_SESSION`.

Comment: Then use a condition to only load the file which is needed instead? `if ($_SESSION['gruppe'] == $h['gruppe']) { include 'menugrp0.html'; }`?

Comment: Please do not use `include` for this, but `echo file_get_contents('menugrp0.html');`

Comment: Alternatively store it in a variable, but then the content of that file needs to be returned, see example 5 http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Daan Meijer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6044167/daan-meijer), this works.

```
  echo file_get_contents('...');    
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['gruppe'] == $h['gruppe']){
    echo 'Foo';
    include ('/path/to/menugrp0.html');
    echo 'Example: one';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
readfile('menugrp0.html'); // Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer. It is like read then "echo"
```

[How to echo the whole content of an .html file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539849/how-to-echo-the-whole-content-of-an-html-file-in-php)