# Read/download large file in PHP without running out of memory

Tags: php, fopen, large-files, fread

How can I read/download a large file in PHP without running into `allowed memory bytes exhausted`?

I am currently trying:

```
$content = null;
while (!feof($file['data'])) {
    $content .= fread($file['data'], 8192);
}

header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file['real_filename'] . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . $file['length']);

echo $content;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to echo the whole content of an .html file in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9539849/how-to-echo-the-whole-content-of-an-html-file-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file['real_filename'] . "\"");
header("Content-Length: " . $file['length']);

while (!feof($file['data'])) {
    print fread($file['data'], 8192);
}
```