# How to Capture PHP Output into a Variable

Tags: php, http-get

I've been wanting to do this because my site does about 3 HTTP requests per page load, because each PHP's output is retrieved with cURL. This is too slow, and I want to avoid using cURL. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171318/how-do-i-capture-php-output-into-a-variable) on Stack Overflow, and it basically does what I want. The accepted answer's suggestion is to use `ob_start();` to start getting output then use `ob_get_clean();` to put the output into a variable. My issue now is that the PHP scripts I'm trying to capture output from need variables passed to them using HTTP Get. The access those variables like this:

```
$term = $_GET['term'];
```

And I don't want to change that, because although I'm going to access these PHP scripts' outputs from another PHP script, I'm also planning on accessing them from elsewhere. So, is there a way to fool these PHP scripts into accepting some arguments through Get, then capturing their outputs with the method suggested above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And I don't want to change that, because although I'm going to access these PHP scripts' outputs from another PHP script, I'm also planning on accessing them from elsewhere. So, is there a way to fool these PHP scripts into accepting some arguments through Get, then capturing their outputs with the method suggested above?

Your question is a bit unclear as to *why* you're using cURL in the first place. If your scripts are on the same server, you can simply set the correct `$_GET` variables and use:

```
<?php
ob_start( );
// include the file.
$_GET['foo'] = 'bar';
include 'the_file.php';

$output = ob_get_clean( );
```

If your scripts are located on another server, where include is not viable, you will **always** have to do a HTTP request to get their contents, regardless of whether your this with cURL or Ajax, or sockets for all I care.

Answer (score 2):

You can $_GET variables from any php script if its set (use [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check that). Then just cURL to such url's will work.

If you have changed the method to POST earlier, you can use `CURLOPT_HTTPGET`. See the curl_setopt functions page (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for more details.

For a non-cURL method, use `jQuery ajax`. It is quite simple to use, just read the documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

**EDIT: This is what you wanted** (haven't checked the code though)

```
<?php

function get_include_contents($filename, $get) {
 if (is_file($filename)) {
    ob_start();
    $_GET = array();
    while (list($key, $val) = each($get)) {
      $_GET[$key]=$val;
    }
    include $filename;
    return ob_get_clean();
 }
 return false;
}

$string = get_include_contents('somefile.php', array('param1'=>'x', 'param2'=>'y'));

?>
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to avoid using cURL because it's slow. That's the point of my question.

Comment: @Hassan You actually said that you are using cURL in first line of your question. Anyways then u can use `jQuery ajax` for this. Just pass the values which you want to send as `get` values in `data` parameter of $.ajax & your output will be received in the success function.

Comment: Yes I'm using cURL, but that is precisely my problem.

Comment: @Hassan Then use ajax! Thats the best solution out there!! I too always use ajax, cURL should be always avoided for scripts.

Comment: AJAX would be just as slow, since it would still have to make several requests to the server. I'm trying to use the method [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171318/how-do-i-capture-php-output-into-a-variable), as described in the question.

Comment: @Hassan ok, just a sec, I got u. will be updating my answer soon

Comment: @Hassan gopi1410 Awesome answer! I like the way of answering it as a function. & iteration using list & each function is cool! never thought of using it in such a way. This should have been the accepted answer!!

Comment: @johntheripper Yes it's a very good answer, and I upvoted it. But I had accepted Berry's answer already when gopi understood what I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

well you can access a $_GET from any script loaded as long as its in the URI, the variable $term can be used in any script. You can also include the script.

When you include a script you can access some of its content after the include.

Comment: Get arguments are sent to specific PHP file. Trying to access them from another file is *not* what I'm trying to do.