# Return files content as include() function

Tags: php, oop, class, methods, include

I have 2 types of pages: Dynamic (which are located in db) and static (file based, like page.php)
I don't want to mess up index.php with bunch of if's or switch's. So I've created class, and methods. Now, What I wanna do is following:

```
$page->getContent($pgdata("token"));
```

getContent function checks page token

- If it's dynamic page, gets content from database and simply echoes the data from db (it's 100% clean)
- If page is static ... Problem starts here
  My static pages are file based. In this case, What I want to do is, to make  function behave as, if I used `include()` instead of `$page->getContent($pgdata("token"));` on `index.php` . What I can do? Read the contents of `$pgdata("token").php` and return as method output? Note: There are php functions inside $pgdata("token").php too. So I can't output $pgdata("token").php file's contents just as string.

Comment: Sounds like you need [output buffering](http://us3.php.net/ob_start)

Comment: I fail to see how this is related to `oop`, `methods` or `class` tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Capture PHP Output into a Variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992910/how-to-capture-php-output-into-a-variable)

Answer (score 1):

```
function getContent($name) {
  ...
  if($static) {
    ob_start();
    include "$name.php";
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    return $content;
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am understanding you correctly, but I believe you're trying to load the contents of a PHP file to a variable? You can do that with output buffering, as above.