# Get render HTML from local PHP file

Tags: php

I have PHP file for make table with data row from database . 
I want send this page to email . but when I get content contains HTML and PHP code . 
but I want send only result of page in HTML.

i use this code

```
    $str =  file_get_contents( 'template.php' );
    $mail = "test@tst.com";
    mail($mail,$str);
```

and this

```
$str = readfile("'template.php'");
```

but result contains php code in email . how i can get only html result?

Comment: Why do you use `'/path/to/template.php'` instead of `/path/to/template.php`? Skip the apostrophes! You can get the content of a PHP file by using output buffers and one of the `include`/`require` functions.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
function getRenderedHTML($path)
{
    ob_start();
    include($path);
    $var=ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean();
    return $var;
}
```

This function will do what you want.

Comment: `return ob_get_clean();`.

Comment: Cannot redeclare connect() (previously declared) . i used connect in template page and need to add in this page too . with this function return error

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents` simply returns file contents, while you need to execute script and take it's output.

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/171327/421752