# Symfony 6, render php file and not twig

Tags: php, symfony

for a really specific project I have to use **PHP files as template** in Symfony, so I render them on my controller, but when I go on the right path in my browser, the PHP isn't interpreted then display code like **html**.

I've know that on older version Symfony it was easy to enable PHP template, but now I didn't find how with Symfony 6.

Does someone know how to do that ?

***Example :***

My index.php path : /templates/gfservphp/index.php

```
#[Route('/index', name: 'app_index_gf')]
public function indexgf(): Response
{
    return $this->render('gfservphp/index.php', [
        'controller_name' => 'MainController',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Hey Noctissei, does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22448438/3808452) help you? It describes a function to render PHP templates and save the output as a string. All you have to do is to return that from your controller, possibly with the appropriate `text/html` content type.

Comment: Might want to consider adding just a tiny bit of code to your question showing how you are doing the rendering.  Keep it simple.  A basic `Hello World` would suffice.

Comment: There is it ! Thanks you

Comment: It can be instructive to read the source code to see what is going on.  AbstractController::render uses twig.  End of story.  Symfony no longer supports any kind of PHP based templating system.  Hasn't for many years.  It is going to be up to you to implement whatever system you are being required to use.

Comment: Ok simple and effective thanks you ahah