# HTML w/ PHP variables into a variable

Tags: php, html, pdf

I need a little help converting a html page into a PDF document using html2pdf

Their site gives a small example

```
$content = "
<page>
<h1>Exemple d'utilisation</h1>
<br>
Ceci est un <b>exemple d'utilisation</b>
de <a href='http://html2pdf.fr/'>HTML2PDF</a>.<br>
</page>";

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php');
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','fr');
$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);
$html2pdf->Output('exemple.pdf');`
```

What I dont know how to do most effectively is make my html page that has a few PHP variables in it into a variable I can use here `$html2pdf->WriteHTML($content);`

is there a way to pull it from its own html file and have the server replace the variables and then make it a variable?

Comment: In the above example the pdf content is just coming from a variable. Are you saying that in your real world usage that `$content` will hold content from a live page somewhere loaded via `curl` or are you trying to load the actual html file from disk? ... or is this just a one off thing where you are trying to convert one single html page?

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/171327/3610351

Comment: if curl would work better. Its for a voucher generator. I have the voucher made to pull some variables from a DB based on the ID passed with GET so I need the content to be the output of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that curl was the best answer to my problem. By using CURL the server processes the page and outputs static HTML that works perfect for HTML2PDF

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/voucher.php?txnid=" .    $txnid);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'My App (http://pexample.com/voucher.php?txnid=' . $txnid . ')');
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

I can then use `$output` where I need it. 
Works exactly as I needed. Thanks!