# What is the best way to generate the .html output base on your .php file?

Tags: php, html, gruntjs

I have an index.php, and I want to grab the .html output of that after it's rendering.

What is the best way to generate the output .html version base on your .php ?

---

## I've tried

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'index.min.php';
echo $content = ob_get_clean();
?>
```

Comment: you will want to look at `output buffering` http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php specifically `ob_get_contents` that you can then write to a file

Comment: Very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/171318/4770933

Comment: @cmorrissey : Thanks, I'm reading through them now.

Comment: @MariM : Mine is not XML.

Comment: Same method, different output.

Comment: I just don't know how would I export it, and call it back. Can you please teach me how ?