# store data of a while loop in a variable

Tags: php

I have a while loop fetching data from mysql database and I need to have them save in an html table format which works as per the below code. However instead of 'echoing' the table rows, is there a way to store the final table with all data in a single variable $finalTable so this way i can just echo $finalTable on any pages I need instead of writing the whole while loop each time:

```
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultX)){
    $page_name = $row['page_name'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$page_name .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$status.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You can pass table to the variable:

```
$finalTable = '<table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultX)){
    $finalTable.='<tr><td>'.$row['page_name'] .'</td><td>'.$row['status'].'</td></tr>';
}
$finalTable .= '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$finalTable = '<table>';
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultX)){
    $page_name = $row['page_name'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $finalTable .= '<tr>';
    $finalTable .= '<td>'.$page_name .'</td>';
    $finalTable .= '<td>'.$status.'</td>';
    $finalTable .= '</tr>';
}
$finalTable .= '</table>'
```

using .= concatenates your all data to a single variable.
Now you can print `$finalTable` to print your table

Answer (score 1):

if your point is to create a html string  you can simply instead of echoing that, create a string and concatenate your table items to it

```
$finalTable ='<table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultX)){
    $page_name = $row['page_name'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    $finalTable .= '<tr>';
    $finalTable .= '<td>'.$page_name .'</td>';
    $finalTable .= '<td>'.$status.'</td>';
    $finalTable .= '</tr>';
}
$finalTable.= '</table>'
//use this variable everywhere you wish
echo $finalTable;
```

`$a .= "x"` mean's assign value of $x to anything it have before plus `"x"`.  this is simplified version of this `$a = $a . "x"`

if you don't want to change your code structure istead of above code you can capture php output buffer that already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171318/how-do-i-capture-php-output-into-a-variable)
this will capture output(at this time the point is echo) into a string instead of write directly into client's browser

```
ob_start();
//your own code
echo '<table>';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultX)){
    $page_name = $row['page_name'];
    $status = $row['status'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>'.$page_name .'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$status.'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
//save it in string variable
$htmlTableData = ob_get_clean();
//echo this one every where you wish
echo $htmlTableData;
```