# How to insert html with php into a variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to write my html into the $response variable, in which I dynamically display posts. How can i do this?
My code to write to a variable:

```js
<ul class="speakers-list">
                    <?php
                    $args = array(  
                       'post_type' => 'speakers',
                        );
                     $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); 
                     while ($loop->have_posts()) :
                      $loop->the_post(); ?>
                         <li>
                             <a href="<?php echo esc_attr(the_permalink())?>">
                            <div class="speaker-img">
                                <?php $img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $loop->post->ID ); ?>
                                <img src="<?php echo $img_url ?>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker-name">
                                <p>
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="speaker-city">
                                <p>
                                    Fribourg
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li> 
                    <?php endwhile;
                     wp_reset_query(); ?>
                </ul>
```

Variable to write html:

```js
  if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
    while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
      $response 'HERE TO ADD HTML'
    endwhile;
  } else {
    $response = 'empty';
  }

  echo $response;
  exit;
```

Comment: What have you tried? `$response = '<h1>Hi</h1>';` should work

Comment: HTML has PHP. May I add the same?

Comment: I dont know what you have/are doing. Please add relevant info to question. You could use a buffer to capture output then put it into variable. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171318/how-do-i-capture-php-output-into-a-variable

Comment: I need to insert a ul with the "speakers-list" class and its content into the $response variable

Comment: See the linked thread, should be able to capture that data and store it to variable with that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me. There is  an equal sign missing between $response and 'HERE TO ADD HTML'.

By using the = sign between the variable and the value, you effectively set the variable on the left to be whatever is on the right.  Then you will be able to reference it the normal way using **$response**

```js
  if($ajaxposts->have_posts()) {
    while($ajaxposts->have_posts()) : $ajaxposts->the_post();
      
/*  BUG RIGHT HERE IS PREVENTING YOUR CODE FROM RUNNING */

/*          $response 'HERE TO ADD HTML' */

/* BUG FIX */
        $response = 'HERE TO ADD HTML';
    endwhile;
  } else {
    $response = 'empty';
  }

  echo $response;
  exit;
```